# How to show Dropbox Images into list view

Tags: android

I want to do get drop box images and show into  the listview. I also getting the Images from Dropbox. I have not understand how to do show it into list view.

I was saw "Android Picasso Dropbox: How to load images into gridview" but not understand. Please Help me

Thanks

Ritika

Comment: which part you don't understand?

Comment: Ritika, can you please show us some code that you currently have and approaches your have tried? And be more specific about what is not working/what do you have problem with?

Comment: How to show it .Into Image View. make URL or Other,I was make URL from image location which are stored into the drop box but URL not uploaded. I am Picasso library for image loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the next steps:

- Make your Dropbox photos public, and create direct URLs, doing this: After you copy the public Dropbox link to your clipboard, just change ?dl=0 to ?raw=1 at the end of the URL.
- Now, you just have to use picasso to retrieve the images with the code

  ```
  Picasso.with(context).load("http://yourpubliclinktodropbox.yourimage?raw=1 ").into(imageView);
  ```

I recommend to you to host your images in another service in order to avoid that change on the dropbox image URL.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks,  guys  for help me . I was solve  my problem .

Comment: You are welcome. If your problem is solved, please mark the answer as solved.

Comment: Hi guys, my Dropbox image path "https://www.dropbox.com/home" and i am use "http://yourpubliclinktodropbox.yourimage?raw=1" link to show image into listview.but image path not created.   Please help me ..Thanks Ritika

Comment: Hi Ritika, the URL  "yourpubliclinktodropbox.yourimage?raw=1" is just an example of URL, you have to replace that URL with a public URL of a picture stored on your Dropbox and replace "?dl=0" with "?raw=1".

Comment: Hi Kelmi, I was use that URL But Its get only single image. I want to fetch all images from Dropbox and show into list view

Comment: Well, then you must have all of your image URL's stored somewhere and then use them one by one for loading the images. For example, you can add it manually to an List<String> and then iterate over it in order to retrieve each one. I'm afraid that dropbox does not have any option for retrieve a list of URL's dynamically.

Comment: Hi Guys, Please ,please help me. I do not show dropbox images into the listview.Please help  Thanks 

Ritika

Comment: @RitikaTomar Could you give us more information please? I thought you solved your problem.

Comment: Hi Kelmi,
I got images name which is stored in Dropbox. But I am not able to create images  URL .Dynamically . Means I am got all images but not show in Listview.

Comment: @RitikaTomar I think the problem is that the public URLs that you created and worked for you in the first instance, does not last forever, this links only works for some time, they are temporal. Because of this reason, I insist and recommend you again storaging your images in another service or server. For ensure this is your problem, if you copy and paste one of theese URLs on your web browser, are you able to display and see the image?

Comment: But I only use dropbox images

Comment: Well, then you just have to upload them to other site.

Comment: Hi Guy's please help me. I don't show Dropbox images into listview Please help me. Please Please